# I want to select dropdown element

Tags: c#, .net, selenium

I want to click a dropdown element. I have mentioned element's xpath/css both. But it is constantly giving error "no element found". I am working on C# on selenium . I have also given dropdown ID first then wait for the dropdown element and then get it clicked but it gives same error always. Any idea ???

Comment: Please edit your question with the code you are using.

Answer (score 0):

It depend of available iFrame or maybe you should switch to default content. It's complicated, without your code.

Any way try this code. It's working for me:

```
private static void ChooseZipCode(IWebDriver wd)
{
    if (!wd.FindElement(By.XPath("//td[@id='divShipStateCombo']/select//option[3]")).Selected)
    {
        wd.FindElement(By.XPath("//td[@id='divShipStateCombo']/select//option[3]")).Click();
    }
}
// where is "[3]" the position your element(ID) in drop down menu
// or
private static void SelectElement(IWebDriver wd, string CardType)
{
    SelectElement cardSelect = newSelectElement(wd.FindElement(By.Name("CardType")));
    cardSelect.SelectByText("Visa Card");
}
```